# Apache2 Auth dbd - md5 hashed password in database, but apache compares it with raw

Tags: hash, config, basic-authentication, apache2.4

I have problem with authenticating in Apache2 via pgsql. Connection to database is successful and if I put hash into password field, it gets authenticated, but how do I make apache 2.4 compare database password with locally inserted password that is not hashed yet. I guess i must put auth hash method to md5 but documentation for some reason is somewhat incomplete.

```
<Location "/something">
    Header add Pragma "must-revalidate no-cache"
    Header add X-RequestTime "%t %D"
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "now"

    AuthName "Something"
    AuthType Basic 
    AuthUserFile "L:\Docs\mgrpass.txt" #does not take usernames and passwords
     #from there anymore. Takes them from database instead.

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    SetEnv ERR_MAIL "sysadmin@mywebsite.com"
    SetEnv SCHEMA   "manager"
    SetEnv AUTHTYPE "manager"

    AuthBasicProvider socache dbd
    AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
    AuthnCacheContext myServer

    # Here should be some hash config to convert local password
    # to md5 encrypted one... Help please :(

    Require valid-user

    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT parool as password FROM _usr WHERE email = %s"

    SetEnv "FORMAT"     "json"

    php_flag pgsql.log_notice off
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag output_buffering off
    php_admin_flag safe_mode_gid on

    Header add X-Timing "%D microseconds"
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Apache parses the password itself. just add {SHA1} or $apr1$ before password

```
AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT CONCAT('{SHA}',parool_sha1) as password FROM _usr WHERE email = %s"
```